# How to add grid lines to a table in a Visual Basic ASP.NET WEB APPLICATION program

Tags: html, css, asp.net, html-table

I want to present a column of questions on the left, and a column of answers on the right, and want grid lines between all, vertical and horizontal lines.
I'm planning to use a TABLE to manage the question and answer controls (text and images).

How can a get a thin black line between each row, and between each column?

Here is my app's .aspx code

```
    .auto-style4 {
        width: 800px;
    }


        <table class="auto-style4">
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style14">What goes on the bun first?</td>
                <td class="auto-style15">cheeseburger</td>
                <td class="auto-style16">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
```

I tried this change, from suggestion below, but it didn't work.

```
        .auto-style4 {
        width: 800px;
        table, th, td { border: 1px solid black; }
    }
```

---

AFTER ADDING SOLUTION, BUT THIS ADDED BORDERS TO *ALL* TABLES

```
.auto-QUESTION_TABLE 
{
    width: 800px;
      border-collapse: collapse; 
}

.auto-QUESTION_TABLE th, td
{
   border: 1px solid black;  
}        .auto-style5 {
            font-weight: normal;
        }
        .auto-style_hhmm_promise {
            width: 500px;
        }
        .auto-style7 {
            font-weight: normal;
            width: 4px;
        }
        .auto-style9 {
            font-weight: normal;
            width: 54px;
        }
        .auto-style11 {
            width: 200px;
        }
        .auto-style13 {
            width: 281px;
        }
        .auto-style14 {
            width: 433px;
        }
        .auto-style15 {
            width: 127px;
        }
        #MediaPlayer {
            width: 498px;
            height: 346px;
        }
        .auto-style16 {
            font-size: small;
        }
    h3
    {margin-top:12.0pt;
    margin-right:0in;
    margin-bottom:3.0pt;
    margin-left:0in;
    line-height:115%;
    page-break-after:avoid;
    font-size:13.0pt;
    font-family:"Cambria","serif";
    }
    </style>
```

...

```
        <table class="auto-QUESTION_TABLE">
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style14">What goes on the bun first?</td>
                <td class="auto-style15">cheeseburger</td>
                <td class="auto-style15">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style14">What is this?<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" Height="52px" ImageUrl="~/cheeseburger.jpg" Width="61px" />
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style15">crow bar</td>
                <td class="auto-style15">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style14" style="background-color:gray;">How do I open a frozen bun</td>
                <td class="auto-style15">
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton4" runat="server" Height="57px" ImageUrl="~/pickles.gif" Width="79px" />
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style15">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style14">Which has more wisdom:&nbsp; The President or a cheeseburger</td>
                <td class="auto-style15">
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton3" runat="server" Height="52px" ImageUrl="~/cheeseburger.jpg" Width="61px" />
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style15">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style14">
                    What goes on the bun first?</td>
                <td class="auto-style15">The President a</td>
                <td class="auto-style15">
                    <asp:Button ID="Button12" runat="server" Text="OK" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style14">
                    &nbsp;</td>
                <td class="auto-style15">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="auto-style15">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style14">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="auto-style15">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="auto-style15">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style14">&nbsp; &nbsp;</td>
                <td class="auto-style15">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="auto-style15">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style14">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="auto-style15">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="auto-style15">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style14">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="auto-style15">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="auto-style15">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: CSS: `table, th, td { border: 1px solid black; }`

Comment: I tried but it didn't work.  Maybe I didn't add it in right.  (see above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.auto-style4 
{
    width: 800px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.auto-style4 th, .auto-style4 td
{
    border: 1px solid black; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/coliveira/UZ9gW/

Comment: Whoops.  This added border okay to the target table, but it ALSO added borders to ALL my HTML tables.  I just want border around just one table.